# I'm having proplem creating table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a database for my project in MYSQL, I have done this hundred times but now I'm stuck and cant figure it out why

```
create table osiguravajuce_drustvo(
od_id int primary key auto_increment,
naziv_drustva varchar(60),
kontakt_info varchar(60),
vo_id int,
constraint fk_osiguranje foreign key (vo_id) references vrste_osiguranja(vo_id)
)engine=innodb

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 13: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table osiguravajuce_drustvo(
od_id int primary key auto_increment,
naziv_' at line 7
```

Comment: What is version of MySQL, can you share the output of "SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S"

Comment: Before creating the table is any command?

Comment: My version of MySQL is 8.0.16
And no there are no commands before creating table. I'm creating whole database with 7 tables. And there are no foreign keys prior to this table.

Comment: I see nothing wrong, pls add more code. Maybe you forgot a `;` at line 12

Comment: Is the table ```vrste_osiguranja``` created prior to creating this table? I create that table and ran this query and it works fine. Maybe a semicolon as suggested above is missing from the statement above

Comment: As the error states the problem is right **before** the `create ...`

Comment: Thanks guys the main problem was i forgot to poot ';' on table before this.
 And forgive me for my lack of know-how in posting and editing here this is my first post on stackoverflow :)